# Error a guardar datos en la bases de datos sqlite3 con c++

Tags: c++, sqlite3

Buenas estoy creando un sistema crud sencillo con c++ y sqlite3 como bases de datos. El programa funciona bien en la compilación pero al momento de pedir los datos al usuario y guardarlo en la bases de datos me sale el error en la condicional "Error en el insertado de Datos" y no se guarda los datos en la bases de datos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string Nombre;
string Apellido;

char* error;
sqlite3* db;
sqlite3_open("prueba.db", &db);

cout<<"Ingrese su nombre"<<endl;
cin>>Nombre;
cout<<"Ingrese su apellido"<<endl;
cin>>Apellido;

string query = "INSERT INTO Alumnos (Nombre, Apellido) VALUES(Nombre, Apellido);";
int rc = sqlite3_exec(db,query.c_str(),NULL, 0, &error);
if(rc != SQLITE_OK){

cerr << "Error en el insertado de Datos" << endl;
        sqlite3_free(error);

}

else{

  cout<<"Datos insertado correctamente"<<endl;

}

sqlite3_close(db);
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

La consulta SQL:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Alumnos (Nombre, Apellido) VALUES(Nombre, Apellido);";
```

Está mal escrita, por dos razones:

- Los valores de tipo string deben ir entre comillas
- La consulta no está haciendo uso de las variables `Nombre` y `Apellido`

Corregido quedaría así:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Alumnos (Nombre, Apellido) VALUES('"
             + Nombre + "', '" + Apellido + "');";
```